# How to prevent unauthorized access to bluetooth speakers?

Tags: bluetooth, speakers

I have the Soundsticks Wireless speakers. They support bluetooth but also have a regular 3.5mm audio jack. My issue is that neighbors can pair with the speakers and play audio and I don't know how to prevent this short of turning off the speakers. Is there any way to prevent unauthorized access? Is there a model of speakers that have a security code or some other feature to limit access?

Comment: Most bluetooth devices require a security code.  If your product does not, then you are out of luck, in some cases the security pin can be changed **check the manual**

Comment: You should certainly provide with more information on the model of your speakers. Without it, other users will be just guessing what may cause the problem. And again, your problem must be formulated as a **problem**, e.g. "I did this, I get result_A, but I want result_B. I tried X, but I get result_C, not result_B".

Comment: Most BT-enabled speakers I've seen use a default code like 0000 or 1234, and don't allow it to be changed. However, for initial pairing and also once paired with a device they generally require a physical button to be pressed to switch to discovery mode. Isn't this the case with your speakers as well? I would find it strange that a speaker would allow just anyone to pair with it without physical access.

Comment: @Karan, the manual says that the code is 0000 "if required". However, I am never prompted for a code, and I doubt my neighbor was prompted for one either.

Comment: @bytebuster, these are the HK Soundsticks Wireless.

Comment: Looks like turning them off whenever you don't specifically plan on connecting with them (bluetooth) may be the only surefire way...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems the Harman Kardon Soundsticks Wireless Speaker System automatically enters pairing mode and becomes discoverable by other devices when turned on, and has no discrete Bluetooth button. As such I don't see any way to limit access to them while they are turned on, and for a product being sold at at such a premium price this seems to be an extremely surprising omission. (Strangely, no widespread complaints about this either as far as I can see.)

As for alternatives, we don't do product recommendations here so just look for a set of speakers that has a physical Bluetooth pairing button. There are lots available.

Comment: Even if I don't use the Bluetooth for audio output, would pairing with the Soundsticks prevent other devices from accessing them?

Comment: I read on one site that the Soundsticks can store up to 8 BT device profiles, but I'm not entirely sure. If you have multiple devices with BT (should be easy enough, almost every phone nowadays does), it should be trivial to test this. Still, even if this works, unless you're ready to keep one device's BT connection tied up and draining power/battery charge, this is not a viable long-term solution.

Comment: I guess I can try wrapping it in aluminum foil

Comment: _"Strangely, no widespread complaints about this either as far as I can see."_ **There are dozens of us!!!!**

Comment: I'm revisiting this and still surprised that there is no option to disable Bluetooth. I'm wondering if it would be worth opening up the unit, finding the Bluetooth module on the chipset and disabling it somehow. If I ever do that I'll post on here my results. Likewise for anybody else.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I've successfully disabled the bluetooth on my HK Nova by removing the green PCB on the bottom side of the main PCB ([shown in this picture](https://imgur.com/a/WWHoUAi)). I'm guessing the Soundsticks have a similar board somewhere.

Comment: @thomasguenzel Awesome! Great job. Thanks for posting. I gave this unit to my brother to use but if I ever get it back, I'll take a look at doing this as well and post any pics of what I find. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an audio jack in the connector.

I don't know, what model you have, or if you even have it after all this years.

I have a cheap Bluetooth headset, that after switching on, lets any device connect to it. Unless there is an audio jack connected. So I simply cut one from an old one headphone, and use it for this purpose.

Comment: Nope. Has no affect on the Bluetooth connection. If you connect over Bluetooth it will just switch to Bluetooth mode and start playing.